# Need some location plugin which is not using FusedLocationProvider

Tags: dart, flutter, location, fusedlocationproviderapi, fusedlocationproviderclient

I need to get current location in my application and I'm using flutter **location** plugin.
I just got this libraries for using location in flutter : 
  **_location, geolocator, geolocation, flutter_geolocation_**
all this libraries are using google fusedLocationProviderClient for getting current and last location updates.
the fused location provider client is not really good in my case because it will work if you have opened the google Maps once before.
check this for getting more details:
[Platform Exception With Error code 'ERROR' in getLocation() method](https://github.com/Lyokone/flutterlocation/issues/97)

My question is, Is there some flutter plugin or library which is using android location provider instead of google fused location provider ?

Sorry for my poor English language.

Comment: Have you tried running it with a location stream listener opened ? I'm using geolocator fine, which is using the fusedlocationprovider. You can also use the option forceAndroidLocationManager with Geolocator, to use that instead of the fusedlocationprovider.

Comment: thanks. i have tried geolocator its not bad just the getCurrentLocation method will take long time to give location Update when you are not moving.